# Calling the welcome message in different template?

Tags: magento2, template

Is it possible to call the default welcome message when user is logged in ("Welcome, customer.fullname") in a different .phtml?

I'd need this message in my `Magento_Customer/templates/account/customer.phtml`

Comment: do you know how to give override?

Comment: Overriding customer.phtml? Sure, but I still don't know how I would call the welcome message.

Comment: please check my answer

Comment: Also share the code of customer.phtml file, where you successfully showing the customer name. I shown you that the info.phtml file that shows the customer name sucessfully.

Comment: Also check your related block and layout file.

Answer (score 0):

This code is from info.phtml file present at `your_project_root/vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/account/dashboard/info.phtml`

```
/** @var \Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Dashboard\Info $block */
?>
<div class="block block-dashboard-info">
    <div class="block-title"><strong><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Account Information')) ?></strong></div>
    <div class="block-content">
        <div class="box box-information">
            <strong class="box-title">
                <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Contact Information')) ?></span>
            </strong>
            <div class="box-content">
                <p>
                   Welcome, <?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getName()) ?><br>
                    <?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getCustomer()->getEmail()) ?><br>
                </p>
                <?= $block->getChildHtml('customer.account.dashboard.info.extra'); ?>
            </div>
```

I edited the above code as Welcome, (added) you can check above code, the above phtml file is linked with the block Info as commented in code, and this relation of block and phtml file is defined in the layout file. 
Similarly, for your file `customer.phtml` you can check the function code in your block or copy the function from Info block or use the additional block of Info also and can solve it.

Please ask me if still you have doubts.